# My app throws error as soon as I updated firebase plugins in flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When I ran the `pod install` command the following result was coming.

```
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_admob: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_analytics: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_crashlytics: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
firebase_remote_config: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/RemoteConfig":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/RemoteConfig (= 6.34.0)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_remote_config (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_remote_config/ios`) was resolved to 0.4.3, which depends on
      Firebase/RemoteConfig (~> 6.33.0)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/RemoteConfig` inside your development pod `firebase_remote_config`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/RemoteConfig` to apply changes you've made.
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually happens when you update your plugins but your podfile.lock is not updated.

**To solve this problem, I did three things**

Step 1:  Delete Podfile.lock

Step 2: run `flutter clean`

Step 3: run `pod install`

Now, run your app, the problem will be solved.